UI Automator cannot find resource-id's with Chrome 121.x
We are testing our OAuth workflow in our App with UIAutomator.
Here's how our test works:
In our test app, after the user clicks on a secured resource, the Chrome browser is launched with our OAuth sign-in page and we use UIAutomator to enter the credentials in the browser, so that we can verify that our app is able to receive the Auth code through the redirect URI.
These test started failing when we upgraded our Chrome version to 121.0.6167.164.
If we uninstall the updates on the Chrome app and downgrade to version 116.0.5845.195, the test start working again.
These test use androidx.test.uiautomator (version 2.2.0) to find the text boxes and enter text in the OAuth sign-in page. This is done by looking for the resource-ids.
Looking at the ui dump, it seems that with Chrome version 121.0.x, UI Automator does not find the resource-id as it comes back as an empty string:
<node NAF="true" index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="tandroid.widget.EditTex"...
This is not happening with Chrome version 116.0.x:
<node NAF="true" index="1" text="" resource-id="user_username" class="android.widget.EditText"...
Upgrading uiatomator to the latest release candidate 2.3.0-rc01 did not fix our issue as the resource-ids are still coming back as empty strings.
Steps to reproduce:
(1) Using uiatomator, the following code will fail with Chrome version 121.0.x
val uiSelector = UiSelector()  
val textBox = UiDevice.findObject(uiSelector.className("android.widget.EditText").resourceId("user_username"))  
textBox.click()  
textBox.setText(text)

Anyone else running into the same issue?
the alternative is to write some other logic to find the text boxes in the chrome browser, which is way more complex.
We can't use Esspresso Web as we are using the Chrome browser not Webviews.

It's entirely unclear what you're even testing. To me the combination of Chrome (or WebView) and android.widget.EditText doesn't provide much meaning, because it's likely an <input/>. Just use Espresso Web instead, which is meant to match such elements.

Apologies for the unclear question. I have updated it with more details.
We cannot use Espresso Web becasue we are not using Webviews.

There still is no HTML, which probably won't feature any android.widget.EditText. Maybe try uiautomatorviewer to get the ID of the element.
